# Recaptcha ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net, validation, recaptcha

I'm using the Recaptcha control in asp.net web forms. And i've faced with the problem about ErrorMessage. How to:

- Set ErrorMessage for it?
- Show (hide) the ErrorMessage if  the   Recaptcha is (isn't) valid?

Answer (score 3):

If you grab the latest source code you should find examples in dotnet/test folder.

ErrorMessage can be set through CustomTranslations property like here: [recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/test/CustomTranslation.aspx.cs](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/test/CustomTranslation.aspx.cs)

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var customTranslation = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        customTranslation.Add("instructions_visual", "Scrivi le due parole:");
        customTranslation.Add("incorrect_try_again", "Scorretto. Riprova.");

        RecaptchaControl.CustomTranslations = customTranslation;

    }
```

The ErrorMessage will be automatically displayed in a ValidationSummary because RecaptchaControl implements IValidator interface.

Comment: What if I have a ValidationSummary? Whatever I write in incorrect_try_again, it shows the errormessage in english!

Comment: This issue is addressed here: http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?id=105 You will need to build latest source